# Fail with error 'This pool does not exist on router1'

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity-0.8.x, decentralized-exchange

I was attempting to make a token swap and got an error: `This pool does not exist on router1.`
This is my transaction: [Etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe891865b49c7374f3add2628dbbc4bddf34d7df4cee35a8a33c613369b67bf9d)

Any idea how I can prevent this error and verify that the pool exists on both routers?

Answer (score 1):

From the transaction the call checks to fetch pool from both router0, router1 factory contracts. So before you make the transaction call verify that you receive non zero address from both the following contract calls:

```
        address pairAddress0 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
        address pairAddress1 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress1).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a closer look at the contract you're trying to interact with, you can see the below lines in the `swap()` function.

```
// Make sure the pools exist on both routers
address pairAddress0 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
require(pairAddress0 != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router0");
address pairAddress1 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress1).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
require(pairAddress1 != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router1");
```

The above lines call the uniswapv2 factory's `getPair()` method to make sure that a Pool exist for the given token with WETH token.

In order to avoid such errors and verify if a pool exist on UniswapV2 before calling swap(), you can add do a similar check to avoid revert:

```
function doesPoolExist(address tokenA, address tokenB) public view returns (bool) {
   address factory = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_V2).factory();
   address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(tokenA, tokenB);
   return pair != address(0); // Making sure the pair address is non-zero
}

function swapTokensToWeth(address tokenA) public {
   require(doesPoolExist(tokenA, WETH), "Pool doesn't exist on UniswapV2");
   // Rest of the logic.
   // pigFoxContract.swap();
}
```